# Daily Rank Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, rank

I have a table with the following headers:

> Dates | Category | Value
>
> 1/1/00 | A | 100
>
> 1/1/00 | B | 200
>
> 1/2/00 | A | 300
>
> 1/2/00 | B | 100

What I would like to do is to be able to add a custom column with the daily rank as such:

> Dates | Category | Value | Rank
>
> 1/1/00 | A | 100 | 1
>
> 1/1/00 | B | 200 | 2
>
> 1/2/00 | A | 300 | 2
>
> 1/2/00 | B | 100 | 1

My goal is to run calcs over the top for average rank, etc. How would I write the DAX code for this column?

Cheers

Comment: please take the [tour] and learn [ask], then edit your question before it gets closed

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a calculated column:

```
Column =
VAR rankValue = 'table'[Value]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        RANK.EQ ( rankValue, 'table'[Value], ASC ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'table', 'table'[Dates] )
    )
```